# Is it possible to use Rails url helpers in classes external to a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing, jruby

I'm just wondering is it possible to utilise the url helpers in an external class? Without loading the entire rails stack, I only really want to get hold of the helpers and not the entire routing engine.

I've thought about including the Rails stack in my external app, however I don't want to be doing that due to performance reasons.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Adam

Comment: Just find in what gem the helpers are defined (if it's in action_view, active_support, or somewhere) and require that specific gem, and you shouldn't have to include the full rails stack.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it should be enough if you include:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helper
```

Comment: That's only the case if Rails is available to the external application, however `Rails` doesn't exist because I don't want to load the entire app up into memory, I just want the URL helpers